# nodeJS - Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: node.js, arrays, express, object, callback

i know this question may be asked about 1000 times here but i cant find the error in my script.
I am trying to iterate through 2 arrays to get a name from an city_id and an organisation_id in a each() loop. i would like to write there values to the "mother"-object to get all informations in one place. Here is the code i've written so far:

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let request = require('request');
let connection = require('../lib/mysql');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if(req.session.loggedin === true){
        getList((err, finlist) => {
           console.log(finlist)
        });
    } else {
        const cssPath = '/stylesheets/style.css'
        res.render('login', { cssPath, title: 'Login' });
    }
});

function getList(callback) {
    var result = [];
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM lists ', (err, rows) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        var r=0;
        rows.forEach(function(item) {
            result[r] = item;
            getCities((err, cty) => {
                result[r].city = cty[item.city_id].name;
                getOrganisations((err, org) => {
                    result[r].organisation = org[item.organisation_id].name;
                });
                callback(result);
            });
            r++;
        });
    });
}

function getCities(callBack) {
    var result=[];
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM cities ', (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        rows.forEach(function (cty) {
            result[cty.id] = cty;
        });
        if (err) {
            callBack(err, null);
        } else {
            callBack(null, result);
        }
    });
}
function getOrganisations(callBack) {
    var result=[];
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM organisations ', (err, rows) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        rows.forEach(function(org) {
            result[org.id] = org;
        });
        if (err) {
            callBack(err, null);
        } else {
            callBack(null, result);
        }
    });
};

module.exports = router;
```

I always get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'city')
    at /opt/alarmprocessor/routes/settings.js:53:32
    . . .
```

which is the line `result[r].city = cty[item.city_id].name;`

King regards for helping me out :)

Tried to set it as an array, as an Object, made console outputs everywhere... seems all to be fine.. Maybe i am too new to NodeJS so it hasnt been clicked in my Head ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occur because `result[r]` doesn't exist line 53. It's declared but doesn't "exist" -> it's `undefined`. If you perform a mere `console.log(result[r]);` line 52 you will get an `undefined`, and you can't set properties (like `city`) to an `undefined` value.
The quick fix would be to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) like this:

```js
result[r]?.city = cty[item.city_id].name;
```

it won't fix your code, it will only stop crashing by ignoring the assignment.